# ImageJ opening imagePlus window as an internal frame inside a desktopPane

Tags: java, imagej

I am having some trouble in ImageJ with one of its files. Basically set up a desktop pane that analyzes and opens images. But when the program opens the image it opens it as a separate JFrame. I would like to be an internal JFrame. So basically the image opens up in the desktop pane. I have tried a couple of things like creating a internal frame class and adding the win to the desktopPane but nothing seems to work it still opens it as a separate JFrame. I was wondering if anyone knows how to do this.

This is my code (this function is just calling .show() to display the image, the code for the actual JFrame that opens the window is in ImageWindow.java):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

FileOpener open = new FileOpener(file);     

ImagePlus fopen = open.open(false);

 if(fopen != null){
    BufferedImage openImage = fopen.getBufferedImage();
    new ImagePlus(path,openImage).show(desktop); //This functions displays the image
    ImagePlus newImage = new ImagePlus(path,openImage);
    img = newImage;


 }
 frame.setVisible(false);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The creation of a new JFrame is hardcoded into ImageJ's [`ImagePlus`](http://fiji.sc/ImagePlus.java#l385) class:

```
if (stackSize>1)
    win = new StackWindow(this);
else
    win = new ImageWindow(this);
```

If you want to adapt the GUI, you can extend the `ImageWindow` or `StackWindow` classes. See the [Trainable Weka Segmentation](https://github.com/fiji/Trainable_Segmentation/blob/master/src/main/java/trainableSegmentation/Trainable_Segmentation.java#L427-429) plugin for a nice example.

Alternatively, use the data structures of [ImageJ2](https://github.com/imagej/imagej), namely [ImgLib](https://github.com/imglib)'s [`ImgPlus`](http://jenkins.imagej.net/job/ImgLib-daily/javadoc/index.html?net/imglib2/meta/ImgPlus.html). These are designed to be independent of any user interface.

Comment: So do I use the imageJ2 files to construct a new imageJ windows. I'm a little confused on how to go about this.

Comment: Sorry if mentioning ImageJ2 caused confusion, this was meant as an alternative approach. A more straightforward example to integrate with the existing GUI can be found the Trainable Weka Segmentation. I added a link to it in an edit to my answer.