# Code displays another image

Tags: java, user-interface, imagej

The following code displays an image when the button is pressed. Custom gui opens an internal frame that displays an image but when it does that it also displays another frame containing the same image, that is separate from the desktop pane that I have created. I don't want that frame to show though. I know ImageJ also displays the image but I don't know where in the code its calling that. I was wondering if anyone could spot out the mistake.

here is my code:

```
 Open.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FileOpener open = new FileOpener(file);
        ImagePlus fopen = open.open(false);

        if(fopen != null){
            BufferedImage openImage = fopen.getBufferedImage();
            //new ImagePlus(path,openImage).show(desktop);

            ImagePlus newImage = new ImagePlus(path, openImage);
            CustomGui gui = new CustomGui(newImage, path, desktop); //This is a customized gui class I created.
            img = newImage;


        }

    }
```

Comment: Could be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23528247/imagej-opening-imageplus-window-as-an-internal-frame-inside-a-desktoppane

Comment: No it didn't fix the problem though, that was for something else.

Comment: Although from quickly skimming over the code of `ImagePlus.java` I'm pretty sure that creating an `ImagePlus` instance causes a new window to be opened (just as desribed by you, and in the linked question), I'm not *absolutely* sure, but maybe someone else can say more about this.